# renameColumn migration fails for existing column with columns does not exist error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I get the error `Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException  : There is no column with name 'price' on table 'class_rooms'.` while running migration to rename the `price` column in `class_rooms` table of my app. The table is created via a migration that runs before this renaming migration through a migration file named `2019_03_13_054619_create_class_rooms_table` with following code

```
class CreateClassRoomsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('class_rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->uuid('yoga_style_id');
            $table->date('start_date')->nullable();
            $table->date('end_date')->nullable();
            $table->time('duration_from')->nullable();
            $table->time('duration_to')->nullable();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->bigInteger('price');
            $table->longText('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('meta_title')->nullable();
            $table->text('meta_description')->nullable();
            $table->text('meta_keywords')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('active')->default(true);
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('yoga_style_id')->references('id')->on('yoga_styles')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            }
        );
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('class_rooms');
    }
}
```

as you can see the price column is defined here. I have `doctrine/dbal` installed and Laravel version I'm using is 5.7.  The rename migration is as follows

```
class RenamePriceClassRoomsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('class_rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn('price', 'cost_subscribed');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('class_rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
        });
    }
}
```

The error I get is

```
Migrating: 2019_04_10_132923_rename_price_class_rooms_table

   Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException  : There is no column with name 'price' on table 'class_rooms'.

  at /Users/anadi/Code/new_web_app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/SchemaException.php:82
    78|      * @return \Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException
    79|      */
    80|     public static function columnDoesNotExist($columnName, $table)
    81|     {
  > 82|         return new self(
    83|             sprintf("There is no column with name '%s' on table '%s'.", $columnName, $table),
    84|             self::COLUMN_DOESNT_EXIST
    85|         );
    86|     }
```

Comment: Have you inspected the database? What column do you find there? ‘price’ or ‘cost_subscribed’ or none of them?

Comment: "price" is the column in this table at the time of migration failure

Comment: it might be possible due to insufficient DB table permission, check if user has access to that DB table? If not then grant privileges to that user.

Comment: the user is owner of the schema, quite baffling actually :-/

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere on this issue? I'm having the same problem and have been banging my head against the wall for a week...

Comment: @KevinFoster No I couldn't find a solution, had to switch to MariaDB.

Comment: have you added `doctrine/dbal` to  `composer.json` ?

Comment: @Hamelraj yes I have the package in `composer.json`

Comment: @KevinFoster could you please check the answer by `Dimitri Mostrey` and let me know if that worked.

Comment: As per [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-modifiers) `Renaming any column in a table that also has a column of type `enum` is not currently supported.` Do you have any `enum` column in `class_rooms` table.

Comment: Try `@Prafulla Kumar Sahu` 's answer and also add a reverse migration in `down()` method.[In `down()` method, check if the `cost_subscribed` exist. if yes, then rename it to `price`] and do a `php artisan migrate:refresh --step=`

Comment: @AnadiMisra - the big integer problem was not applicable to *my* problem. I'm not sure if it's directly applicable to *your* problem, but I ended up finding that this error is sometimes thrown because of insufficient table permissions to the schema tables - a real head scratcher... Basically it reads from the schema table, and if you don't have permissions, it returns null rather than an array of column names or an error, so it says "column doesn't exist" - took me a week to find that... I granted table permissions and everything ran fine. - If this works for you I can write up a full answer.

Comment: @KevinFoster yes that'll be good to have :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are some known issues with innoDB and biginteger column types. Looking at bug reports, it's not clear if they have fixed this. For example https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15383

In your case, the column name is `price`, it stands to reason that changing the column type to integer won't corrupt the existing values. In case, the column isn't part of a foreign key neither. This is a possible solution.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('class_rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('price')->change();
            $table->renameColumn('price', 'cost_subscribed');
            //  $table->bigInteger('price')->change(); //->optional
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems the column is already renamed, you can check your table, but better way to do it is check the column exists or not before renaming it, if the column does not exists, you can just create a column with your desire name and type

```
class RenamePriceClassRoomsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if (Schema::hasColumn('class_rooms', 'price')) {
            Schema::table('class_rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->renameColumn('price', 'cost_subscribed');
            });
        } else {
           Schema::table('class_rooms', function($table) {
               $table->integer('price')->after('<some_column>');
           });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('class_rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
        });
    }
}
```

or even choose to just add the column you want to add and delete the existing column if exists, but only if there is no data or you can use DB::raw() to copy the data from one column to another once the column is created and after it is done remove the column.

```
Schema::table('class_rooms', function($table) {
       $table->integer('cost_subscribed')->after('<some_column>');
   });
   if (Schema::hasColumn('class_rooms', 'price')) {
        Schema::table('class_rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('price');
        });
    }
```

There is a closed issue in mysql, that may be the cause of this issue, the issue describes as follows.

```
Updating a row on an updatable ResultSet with a BigInteger object on an UNSIGNED INT fails. A MysqlDataTruncation is throwned when updateRow() is executed.
```

and suggested an workaround:
insert the value as a String, not only string using integer will also work. But as per current update with new [commit](https://lists.mysql.com/commits/266) have already fixed it, so it should not occur in new versions of mysql.

Comment: It's not renamed when I check the schema at the time of failure.

Comment: @AnadiMisra in that case, it seems the when you are creating the column may be some special character got added to column and now the column name is not matching, that is why it is giving you result `no column with price` or may be the encoding of table during creation and renaming is different.

Comment: @AnadiMisra can you share your migration code for table creation, that may give me better idea of your issue?

Comment: it's there in the question already both the initial migration and rename migration code

Comment: @AnadiMisra it seems you have already got the solution in Dimitri's answer, is that working for  you or you are still having issue with that?

Comment: yup got it to work, took time to setup the db again though. thanks for your help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried migrating this before, but failed in the middle or if you have rolled this back before but not the create table migration, it is possible that you have already renamed the table since the function will not rename itself back to 'price'.
However, it is not for sure as I don't have the information of what migrations you ran before this.

Comment: I ran migration reset before running it again and saw the database being restored to prestige every time I did that.

Answer (score 0):

First check in your **class_rooms** has **price** column.
if you have that column then as per documentation you have to install **doctrine/dbal** package

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Then try

```
class RenamePriceClassRoomsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('class_rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn('price', 'cost_subscribed');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('class_rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn('cost_subscribed','price');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have doctrine as mentioned in the question, missing doctrine or syntax of migration wasn't the issue here